# Ruby Combine Hash Key As Hash + Key and return as array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose I have a hash

hash = {"123"=>"abc", "124"=>"def"}

I'm expecting output

[["123 - abc", "123"], ["124 - def", "124"]] so that I could pass it to my select tag to display the "123 - abc" and to submit the id when selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a solution

hash.map{|key,value| ["#{key} - #{value}",key]}

But is there a better way other than this?

Comment: If you were able to find solution within one minute of posting. Better spend more time on debugging from next time. Happy coding :)

Comment: Bijendra I had to submit the code today but I'm not sure it will go through the review phase[FYI] and I didn't want anybody to post the same answer.BTW If you were concentrating more on the posting time than the content may be even you can spend ample time debugging ;)